# yarn build (yarn encore production) not working, it creates empty build folder

Tags: webpack-encore, yarn-v2

I am trying to make my app production build and `yarn build` or `yarn encore production`
creates just empty public/build folder.
But if i use `yarn dev` or `yarn encore dev` it builds all js and css and other files perfectly.
Why `yarn build` is not working?

Comment: Does it show any information? And what's your webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. I remove yarn.lock file, cleaned the yarn cache.
Run `yarn install` and `yarn encore prod` OR `yarn encore dev` again. It worked for me.